# Good resource for daily Sudoku Puzzles

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku, reference-request

I love solving puzzles, It keeps my brain active. Previously I used to solve newspaper "Sudoku" which were fairly easy. Then I solved some interesting puzzles in the book below.

> Mastering Sudoku week by week-Paul Stephens

I'm looking for any good website that offers medium to hard daily sudoku puzzles. Can anybody suggest me any good website, where I can get daily sudoku puzzles.

Comment: Just for fun: https://www.producthunt.com/posts/magic-sudoku-arkit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Web Sudoku](http://websudoku.com) has huge amounts of puzzles across five difficulty levels. You don't even have to wait a day for new ones.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are looking for printable Sudoku puzzles and variations you can checkout
www.FunWithPuzzles.com

Sudoku Variations page is as given below
http://www.funwithpuzzles.com/2017/02/sudoku-variations-index-page.html

Answer (score 0):

> [This website](http://www.conceptispuzzles.com/de/index.aspx) has a few good ones for free (among other logic puzzles).
>  I think you would need to subscribe though if you want to get new ones on a regular basis.

Comment: ...Why did you put that in a spoiler?

Answer (score 0):

[Sudokucup](http://sudokucup.com) has daily classic and variant Sudoku. Some of the best Sudoku solvers in the world participate.

[Fed-Sudoku](http://www.fed-sudoku.eu/enindex.php?co=) is has daily easy/medium/hard classic Sudokus, as well as some less frequent variants.

Answer (score 0):

A (relatively) new website is

https://sudokumaniacs.com/

where you can register and login to play classic Sudoku as well as new variants on a daily basis.